# Google Pubsub Error 16: Unauthenticated: Failed to retrieve auth metadata occurs when server running for a long time

Tags: google-oauth, publish-subscribe, google-cloud-pubsub, apollo-server

I have this strange issue that keeps occurring with my google pub sub service.  When I start my server, the google pub sub service works and there doesn't seem to be an issue.  When I leave my server running for prolonged periods of time (a day or more), once in a while, I get the following error out of nowhere.

```
Error: 16 UNAUTHENTICATED: Failed to retrieve auth metadata with error: request to https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND www.googleapis.com
    at Object.callErrorFromStatus ~\<project_path>\node_modules\@grpc\grpc-js\src\call.ts:81:24)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (~\<project_path>\node_modules\@grpc\grpc-js\src\client.ts:338:36)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (~\<project_path>\node_modules\@grpc\grpc-js\src\client-interceptors.ts:426:34)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (~\<project_path>\node_modules\@grpc\grpc-js\src\client-interceptors.ts:389:48)
    at ~\<project_path>\node_modules\@grpc\grpc-js\src\call-stream.ts:276:24
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:78:11)
[ERROR] 08:21:29 Error: 16 UNAUTHENTICATED: Failed to retrieve auth metadata with error: request to https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND www.googleapis.com
```

If this was a credentials issue, I should see this UNAUTHENTICATED error as soon as my server starts but this is hard to diagnose because it happens randomly after a set period of time.  Has anyone encountered this type of error with Google Pubsub?
I do have a generated Credentials file that you can get from your google developer console for OAuth.  It has the following keys
(type, project_id, private_key_id, private_key, client_email, client_id, auth_uri, token_uri, auth_provider_x509_cert_url, client_x509_cert_url).

I only use the project_id, private_key, client email.  Do I need to use the others in order to stop this error from occuring?  I think I linked directly to the credentials file before using an .env variable as per the [google pubsub package docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@axelspringer/graphql-google-pubsub) and still got the same error.  I know with Oauth, there is a refresh token timer of a couple of days and was wondering if that could be the cause of this. The refresh token isn't being picked up and therefore google apis cant authenticate.  That's just a wild guess though.  Any help would be much appreciated.

My code is below to access the service.

**package.json**

```
"@axelspringer/graphql-google-pubsub": "^2.1.0",
"googleapis": "^92.0.0",
"express": "^4.17.1",
"express-serve-static-core": "^0.1.1",
"cors": "^2.8.5",
"cookie-parser": "^1.4.5",
"apollo-server": "^3.5.0",
"apollo-server-core": "^3.5.0",
"apollo-server-express": "^3.5.0",
"graphql-tools": "^7.0.2",
"subscriptions-transport-ws": "^0.11.0",
```

**src/index.ts**

```
import { GooglePubSub } from "@axelspringer/graphql-google-pubsub";
const express = require("express");
const cookies = require("cookie-parser");
import cors from "cors";
import { createServer } from "http";
import { makeExecutableSchema } from "@graphql-tools/schema";
import { ApolloServer } from "apollo-server-express";
import {
  ApolloServerPluginLandingPageGraphQLPlayground,
  ApolloServerPluginLandingPageDisabled,
} from "apollo-server-core";
import {
  ConnectionContext,
  ConnectionParams,
  SubscriptionServer,
} from "subscriptions-transport-ws";

const pubSubOptions = {projectId: <GOOGLE project_id>, credentials: {client_email: <GOOGLE client_email>, private_key: <GOOGLE private_key>} }

const pubsub = new GooglePubSub(pubSubOptions);

const context = async ({ req, res, connection }: MyContext) => {
  const msgHeader = connection ? connection.context : req;
  return {
    req,
    res,
    pubsub,
  };
};

(async function () {
  const app = express();
  app.use(cors());
  const httpServer = createServer(app);

  const schema = makeExecutableSchema({
    typeDefs,
    resolvers,
  });

  const server = new ApolloServer({
    schema,
    context,
    plugins: [
      process.env.NODE_ENV === "development"
        ? ApolloServerPluginLandingPageGraphQLPlayground()
        : ApolloServerPluginLandingPageDisabled(),
      {
        async serverWillStart() {
          return {
            async drainServer() {
              subscriptionServer.close();
            },
          };
        },
      },
    ],
  });

  const subscriptionServer = SubscriptionServer.create(
    {
      schema,
      execute,
      subscribe,
      onConnect: (
        connectionParams: ConnectionParams,
        webSocket: WebSocket,
        ConnectionContext: ConnectionContext
      ) => {
        const context: any = {
          pubsub,
        };

        return context;
      },
    },
    { server: httpServer, path: server.graphqlPath }
  );

  await server.start();
  app.use(cookies());
  server.applyMiddleware({ app });

  const dbUri = db_url();

  try {
    await mongoose.connect(dbUri, configs.MONGO_OPTIONS);
  } catch (err) {
    if (err instanceof Error) {
      throw new Error(err.message);
    }
    process.exit(1);
  }

  httpServer.listen(PORT, () =>
    console.log(
      ` Server ready at ${configs.apiURL}:${PORT}${server.graphqlPath}`
    )
  );
})();
```

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Answer (score 1):

It is probable that the error is occurring due to a token expiration, generally the Token expiration time is 1hr, but Oauth token expiration time varies depending on the [token type](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/create-short-lived-credentials-direct?hl=en#sa-credentials-about).

You can obtain the information associated with a valid (not expired or revoked) access token using the [tokeninfo API](https://any-api.com/googleapis_com/oauth2/docs/Miscellaneous/oauth2_tokeninfo) using an endpoint:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?access_token=<access_token>
```

This endpoint will throw you data as:

```
{
  "access_type": "",
  "audience": "",
  "email": "",
  "expires_in": 0,
  "issued_to": "",
  "scope": "",
  "token_handle": "",
  "user_id": "",
  "verified_email": true
}
```

The important data in this is `expires_in` this will let you know the number of seconds until the token expires.

Adittionally you need to write the code to anticipate possibilities of expiration. In this [document](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2#expiration) are the common reasons why a Token might stop working.